# How to get expiration date and flags associated with a cookie from Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#, c++, internet-explorer

I can get the value of a cookie with [InternetGetCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384710%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [InternetGetCookieEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But I 'd like to get the expiration date and the flags (httpOnly, secure) as well as the data. I couldn't find a function (C++ or C#) that allows me to do that from within Internet Explorer (a BHO).

Comment: Would you understand this question if someone asked you?

Comment: so you're creating a BHO in C#? I'm still not sure what [InternetGetCookie][1] is... might be helpful if you supply some background\context and maybe some sample code...

Comment: I've fixed the links, the don't work inside code blocks

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Net;
using System;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(<your URL>);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

// Print the properties of each cookie.
foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Cookie:");
  Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", cook.Name, cook.Value);
  Console.WriteLine("Domain: {0}", cook.Domain);
  Console.WriteLine("Path: {0}", cook.Path);
  Console.WriteLine("Port: {0}", cook.Port);
  Console.WriteLine("Secure: {0}", cook.Secure);

  Console.WriteLine("When issued: {0}", cook.TimeStamp);
  Console.WriteLine("Expires: {0} (expired? {1})", cook.Expires, cook.Expired);
  Console.WriteLine("Don't save: {0}", cook.Discard);    
  Console.WriteLine("Comment: {0}", cook.Comment);
  Console.WriteLine("Uri for comments: {0}", cook.CommentUri);
  Console.WriteLine("Version: RFC {0}" , cook.Version == 1 ? "2109" : "2965");

  // Show the string representation of the cookie.
  Console.WriteLine ("String: {0}", cook.ToString());
}
```