# how to get expire date from cookies file

Tags: c#, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get expiration date and flags associated with a cookie from Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934826/how-to-get-expiration-date-and-flags-associated-with-a-cookie-from-internet-expl)

**How to get expire date from cookies file**

my cookies likes this:

> UserInfo
>   6pzYKskEcx7lflixFLGmBhv4+SUOt+G75z0ASsu91SzDPS0WfW4Q+7nud+ljldfEuDotv86J6gcG+ZX7qNFRFNGeH1wt7Y3XkRuRwUH7xh69fcsoePvz8fBITBM0qpnj3iOoD4bOOJ/fdAhbZ7aTlEhx0lTV4ZLyBXeras944F7FtAYxiU/let4x9U8rB+2R
>   127.0.0.1/ 1024 3442423040 30339635 729453404 30267216
>   *

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934826/how-to-get-expiration-date-and-flagas-associated-with-a-cookie-from-internet-exp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gets or sets the expiration date and time for the Cookie as a DateTime.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.expires(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: thanks,but I want to get the expires from the text,not the response.

Comment: The browser is responsible for managing cookies, and the cookie's expiration time and date help the browser manage its store of cookies. 

[Check Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809072/c-sharp-asp-net-getting-cookie-expiration-time-set-in-javascript-always-returns)

Comment: I have read that article,but I still do not understand。
I used .net client,not browser.I can get the name and value from the cookies string ,but the expires I don`t know.